# PPT VBA Code working on one computer but not another

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am wanting to display some information from an excel file in a PPT presentation and have the OLE objects update automatically in slide show view when the presentation restarts. I am doing this to showcase production information in our main office.

So my code seems to work perfectly fine on my desk computer, however, when I put the presentation up on the computer and TV in the prod office it does not run. I have it opening the excel file and refreshing all of the data then saving the file (had to put in a delay so that the excel file could finish refreshing before the save). Next, I have it going through the presentation slides searching for objects and updating them from the excel file. Finally, the workbook and excel application are closed. I have it setup to repeat these steps every time it gets to slide one with the presentation set on a loop.

Frist time ever coding something in PPT and I know some of the commands are different so I just want them to get double checked. Because I am confused as to why it works perfectly on my computer and not the other.

```
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange()
Dim i As Integer
i = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.CurrentShowPosition
If i <> 1 Then Exit Sub

Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWorkBook As Object

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True

Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("G:\Welding\Daily Updates\Production Info Tracking\TV Display Links.xlsm", True, False)
xlWorkBook.RefreshAll

Dim WAIT As Double
WAIT = Timer
While Timer < WAIT + 5
   DoEvents  'do nothing
Wend

xlWorkBook.Save

For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each sh In sld.Shapes
        If sh.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then
            sh.LinkFormat.Update
        End If
    Next
Next

xlWorkBook.Close
xlApp.Quit

Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlWorkBook = Nothing

bcheck = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? Did you step through the code to see where it fails?

Comment: I get no error message when I attempt to run in on the prod office computer. Debug highlights the line 3 but it also highlights this on my desk computer, yet the code functions perfectly. Hence my confusion on how the  code can run fine on one computer but not another.

Comment: It highlights line 3 as an error because it can't run that code outside of slideshow view and obviously I have the VBA window pulled up.

Comment: I'm afraid I can not help you. Your code works fine on my machine as well. Unrelated to the problem, you don't need to do the timer loop. `DoEvents` itself will [Yield execution so that the operating system can process other events.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doevents-function)

Comment: @horst Yeah, I can't seem to figure out what the difference the computer is making either. I've checked the security and trust settings, heck, I've checked everything I can think of. Thanks for testing it and for the link.

Comment: SOLVED IT!!! It was the craziest thing...so apparently the Developer window has to be open for the code to run automatically in slide show view in PPT. Since I was editing at my desk with that window opened it worked fine. But I wasn't opening it in the prod office because I was only trying to view the presentation. Figured it out by accident when it failed to run at my desk and after TWO days I finally put two and two together! haha.